# Printed parsed json from escaped json string but can't able to access anything from it on lambda with node 12.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, aws-lambda

Here is the code { lambda nodejs 12.x }.

```
console.log("body", event.body);
var request = JSON.parse(event.body)
console.log("parsed body", request["operation"], request['"operation"'], request.operation, request);
```

[image]

result through log.

[image]

```
2021-02-16T13:54:01.357Z    78ca4692-b31d-40b2-bc32-e993a622aaa0    INFO    body "{\"operation\":\"getDevice\"}

2021-02-16T13:54:01.357Z    78ca4692-b31d-40b2-bc32-e993a622aaa0    INFO    parsed body undefined undefined undefined 
{
    "operation": "getDevice"
}
```

How to I access data from the object using .key or ["key"] methods

** I am checked this on browser cli it works but not on lambda I don't know what I am done wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Do a little debugging and make sure that the `event.body` is in proper JSON format. The `JSON.parse` should work if everything is fine

Comment: It's not `JSON.parse(request).operation`, is it? Please do a `console.log(typeof request)` and show us the results

Answer (score 0):

I am solved this.
on the first time on JSON.parse returns normal json string from escaped json.
I am passed these json string to another JSON.parse it retured object.
someone check this out and report this bug.